# Is There a Standard Metric for Evaluating Treatment Impact Considering Action Cost in Uplift Models?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, causality, treatment-effect

I'm currently exploring Uplift modeling, specifically the use of the **Conditional Average Treatment Effect (CATE) metric**:

$$ \tau(t', t, x) := \mathbb{E}[Y | X=x, T=t'] - \mathbb{E}[Y | X=x, T=t] $$

This metric measures the expected outcome difference for a set of variables `x` under two conditions: treatment `t’` (group receiving a discount) and control `t` (in that context this is the control group which not receiving an offer and the cost is 0).

My question is about integrating the cost of treatment actions into this evaluation. I'm considering a simple expected value formula like:

$$ \tau_c(t', t, x, c) := \mathbb{E}[Y | X=x, T=t'] \cdot c - \mathbb{E}[Y | X=x, T=t] $$

where `c` denotes the cost of action in the treatment group.

**Is there a common metric in the literature that considers the cost of the treatment action?**